# Power BI Desktop how to subtract a value from a row using new measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am using Power BI Desktop an want to calculate a new measure subtracting 126 from a row value. I start with:

[image]

I then add:

```
Reassign = calculate (sum('sdowner SPV_REP_PERSONALTAB'[Total]) - 126)
```

This results in:
[image]

How do I perform this calculation without adding all these extra rows please?

Answer (score 1):

It might suffice to test for the value not being blank using IF and a variable to avoid duplicate calculations, like for instance

```
Reassign =
VAR ValSum =
    CALCULATE( SUM( 'sdowner SPV_REP_PERSONALTAB'[Total] ) )
RETURN
    IF( NOT ISBLANK( ValSum ), ValSum - 126 )
```